# How to make Hangouts stop sending me SMS messages?

Tags: sms, google-hangouts, chat

I've tried out the SMS feature of Hangouts app, which allows you to handle SMS within itself instead of the default one.

I didn't like it for certain reasons, so I disabled it.

However, for some reason, almost each time anyone sends me something via Hangouts (from a PC for example), I get it in both Hangouts and via SMS (with phone number that looks like "1000274" ). That's right - I get 2 messages - one for hangouts and one is an SMS message shown on the normal messaging app.

Why does it happen? How can I stop it from happening?

I hope it's a bug and that it will get fixed soon... :(

NOTE: I have Android 4.3 on a Galaxy S3 I9300 device.

Comment: Are you using a Google Voice number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think they've fixed it some weeks ago, as I didn't notice any new SMS message that comes after a real hangouts message.

Answer (score 4):

Go to

- **Settings** -> Under data usage tap **More**
- Tap **Default SMS app** and select your SMS app

[image]

Source with detailed instruction: http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57613499-285/manage-default-sms-app-on-android-4.4-kitkat/

Comment: sadly I don't have kitkat. I have Android 4.3...

Comment: @androiddeveloper, does this not work on 4.3?

Comment: @dotVezz android 4.3 doesn't have this option on the settings of the device. I was talking about the feature within the Hangouts app... Only android 4.4 has the ability to choose which app is the default SMS app...

Answer (score 1):

The functionality is different with Kitkat as you can choose your default SMS application in the Wireless & Network settings. Below is for 4.4 and for 4.3 and below. 
Open the [google-plus-hangouts](/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts) application.

**For Android 4.4+ (Kitkat)** (As per the above):

Click on **Menu** then **Settings**.

Click on **SMS**.

Click on the setting "**SMS Enabled**" under the General heading and change your default SMS application.

[image]

---

**For 4.3 (Jelly Bean) and Below:**

Click on Menu then Settings.

Click on SMS.

Untick the setting "**Turn On SMS**"

[image]
<sub>(source: [cbsistatic.com](http://asset1.cbsistatic.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim2/2013/11/08/Hangouts_disable_SMS.png))</sub>

Comment: well as i've already written, i've already disabled this functionality. the problem is that for about half of the messages i get via hangouts, i also (in addition) get an SMS containing those messages.

Comment: Have you uninstalled hangouts and reinstalled it? Have you installed any other 3rd Party apps for SMS and reset your default? I know my answer is generic, but I wasn't sure WHAT you had disabled already. I've not seen this issue on the S3, S4, Nexus 4, Nexus 7, HTC One, HTC Desire X or any of my other devices. I wanted to give a generic answer, and assumed you had cleared all data, reinstalled, rebooted etc. Are you getting IMs from Hangouts converted into SMS? The wording is not clear to me on your question. Are you rooted, running custom firmware?

Comment: I'm not sure how should I write this problem. For almost each message I get via hangouts (that someone writes to me via his PC, for example), I also get the exact same message to both hangouts and the SMS messaging app, and it's really an SMS message, with a weird phone number as I've written. I've now updated my question. hope now it's clear.

Comment: Ok that's totally clear now, that's very very odd. Did you reinstall hangouts from scratch (delete data and cache, uninstall and reinstall)? Do you have a different SMS app, or the default one that came with your device. Sorry I can't be of more help, but I'll keep looking for you. Something very odd going on there.

Comment: I've now tried to clear the data of the app. It didn't work. In fact, I think it got worse (or maybe it was like that before too) : now some messages are sent only as SMS, plus video calls request don't always get to be received ... :(

Comment: But before reaching to this setting in case of android 4.3 you need to update your Hangouts using google play store, otherwise setting for sms will not appear in the setting menu of Hangouts....

Answer (score 1):

I've recently flash a custom ROM called "OmniRom" (AOSP, Kitkat based), and I think this problem is now gone.

Not sure why it occurred, and why I don't see it anymore.

Maybe it's because of a bug on 4.3.